# $\sum_{i=1}^{10}i^n = 3$ (mod 10) $\forall 4n, n \in \mathbb{N}$, and 5 (mod 10) $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ that are not multiples of 4.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

A few years ago I found this result while toying with summations, and stumbled upon it while digging through old notes recently. I'll summarize the problem and result below, but ***I have no proof or intuition of this result, and that is why I am posing it here***.

The title of this post is a fairly encompassing explanation for the problem itself. Taking the sum from $i=1$ to $i=10$ of $i^n$ yields 5 (mod 10) for every natural number $n$ except those that are multiples of 4, in which the summation yields 3 (mod 10). This is, I suppose, still conjecture though, as I have no formal proof of this result, and certainly no intuition as to why it is multiples of 4 as opposed to any other.

I figured I'd put it out to the world and see what you all think about it. Thanks! J.R.

Comment: Note that $i^{n+\color{blue}4}\equiv i^n\bmod10$ [since](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function#Exponential_cycle_length) $10$ is square-free

Comment: @j.w.Tanner that is a little sloppy. Since $10$ is square-free the cycle is sure to start at $1$, but we don't have a period of $4$ for all bases. Need to include the fact that $4$ is the totient of $10$ to complete the logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main fun in this is looking at how $i^n \equiv 10$ changes with $n$. Here is a table.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ \hline 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
2 & 2 & 4 & 8 & 6 & 2 & 4 \\ \hline
3 & 3 & 9 & 7 & 1 & 3 & 9 \\ \hline
4 & 4 & 6 & 4 & 6 & 4 & 6 \\ \hline
5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 \\ \hline
6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 \\ \hline
7 & 7 & 9 & 3 & 1 & 7 & 9 \\ \hline
8 & 8 & 4 & 2 & 6 & 8 & 4 \\ \hline
9 & 9 & 1 & 9 & 1 & 9 & 1 \\ \hline
10 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
\end{array}
The left most column are the numbers $i$ and the top column is the number $n$ and the rest of the table is filled in according to $i^n \equiv 10$. Notice that columns 1 and 5 are equal and columns 2 and 6 are equal. If we continue this table for bigger $n$ it will always be the case that the $n$ and $n+4$ columns are precisely equal. This can be noted by the fact that within each row the patterns repeat with cycle lengths 1,2, or 4 and therefore the columns synchronize every LCM(1,2,4) = 4  iterations.

Now if we sum the columns we get
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ \hline 
45 & 45 & 45 & 33 & 45 & 45 \\ \hline 
5 & 5 & 5 & 3 & 5 & 5 \\ \hline
\end{array}
where the top row is the power $n$, the second row is the total sum, and the last is the sum mod 10. Again because the columns are repeating every four iterations their sum and sum mod 10 also repeat every four iterations (it could have happened to be fewer than four but in this case it didn't).

Overall, this explains why the 5-5-5-3 pattern repeats. The fact that it is 5-5-5-3 is essentially just by chance. For example if you sum the first 11 numbers you end up with a 6-6-6-4 pattern and the first 12 numbers gives a 8-0-4-0 pattern.

Overall the real trick is in spotting that the columns of the first table are on a cycle of length 4, and the rest is mostly arithmetic. For a fun investigation you can also extend the table vertically and show that the $i$th row equals the $(i-10)$th row. This can be used to show neat facts like $\sum_{i=1}^{100} i^n \equiv 10 = 0$ for every $n$.

Comment: Great eye! I have just corrected them.